# Show the HTML5 notification only when the tab or page is not active or on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a websocket on my chat App and HTML 5 notification. I'm trying to use the HTML 5 notification when there's a message coming from the server and when the current page,tab is not active or not on focus (you're at other stuff, you're not on the chat app window/page), so here when there is a message from the server

```
//set global var
var nnn=false,Notification = window.Notification || window.mozNotification || window.webkitNotification;

//connect to the websocket server
conn = new WebSocket('ws://mysite.com:9090');

//function for handling the message from the server
conn.onmessage = function(e) {
show_n(e.data);
}

//detect if on page/active/focus or not on page/out focus
$(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {
    var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

    if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
        switch (e.type) {
            case "blur":
                nnn=true;
                break;
            case "focus":
                console.log("false");
                nnn=false;
                break;
        }
    }

    $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
});

//HTML 5 notification
Notification.requestPermission();
function show_n(message) {
    console.log(nnn);
    if(nnn===true){
        Notification.requestPermission(function(perm){
            if(perm==="granted"){
                var instance = new Notification(
                    "New Message", {
                        body: message
                    });
             }else{
                 Notification.requestPermission();
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is the 'nnn' variable is always true in weither I switch tab or on the page so the notification is always showing even when I'm on the page which I don't want, supposedly If im not on the page (goes unto other tabs, or doing other stuff on the other side of the browser) or page is not on focus/not active, the 'nnn' variable should set to true, else if I'm on the page (active/on focus) the 'nnn' should set to false. But if I just don't show the HTML 5 notification (not trigger the HTML 5 notification event) and log the blur and focus event, it shows 'true' or 'false' which is correct. Any ideas, clues, suggestions, help, recommendations please?

Comment: Can you edit your question please, and rephrase your last paragraph (the problem description)?  It's not clear to me what you mean and you seem to contradict yourself (variable is always true, or is correct?)

Comment: @GolezTrol: Please see my updated post.

Comment: Can you log the blur event too. Maybe it's firing too often or in the wrong order.

Comment: I tried to log everything. If im on or off the tab or page, i got this log sequence, 'true' 'false' which is right, but when the message arrive from the server, the 'nnn' variable sets to always 'true' weither im on page/active tab/on focus or out the page/tab page not on focus, any ideas?

Comment: I guess the 'on focus' event trigger when there is a message coming from the server even the page is out of focus or not active.

Comment: It works for me FF45 with setTimeout for show_n.
But I suggest switching to a non global variable or checking prevType directly.

Comment: It may sound stupid, but I have to mention it. Switching to the browser console in inspector tools or something like that is firering the blur event on the window.